# gdb core file analysis

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump

I have core file and I am trying to find out what might have caused the app to crash & generate core file. When I run core file with gdb and binary, I get got below on gdb prompt:
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x08d0290f in McSystem::RWCString2RWTime (from=..., to=...) at McSystem.cpp:1613

when I run the disassemble with above address, I got below in gdb:

```
(gdb) disas 0x08d0290f
Dump of assembler code for function McSystem::RWCString2RWTime(STSString const&, STSTime&):
   0x08d02907 <+19>:    push   %ebx
   0x08d02908 <+20>:    push   %eax
   0x08d0290c <+24>:    lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
=> 0x08d0290f <+27>:    push   %eax
   0x08d02910 <+28>:    call   0x8da7aa0 <STSTime::STSTime(STSString const&, STSZone const&, STSLocale const&)>
   0x08d02915 <+33>:    add    $0x10,%esp
   0x08d0291e <+42>:    push   %eax
   0x08d0291f <+43>:    call   0x8da8010 <STSTime::isValid() const>
```

From above the line marked by arrow has problem. But I am not able to understand the cause here.
Issue is not related to memory violation I guess. When I print eax I got below value:

```
(gdb) print $eax
$1 = 1684480973
```

Any thoughts would appreciated...

Comment: Can you run the `bt` (backtrace) command? The `push` instruction will fail if the stack has run out of space.

Comment: When run bt command got below:                                                                                             #8  0xf7bb3548 in ?? ()
#9  0x09ec9e20 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `0x08d0290f <+27>:    push   %eax`

When a crash happens on `PUSH` or `CALL` instruction on Intel machines, 99.999% of the time it is caused by stack overflow.

Examine the value of the `ESP` register, and chances are it's at or just below page boundary.

Look at the output from GDB `where` command -- you may have infinite recursion, or you could be using very large stack allocations.